# Maven release Cannot perform the release to pass protected repository

Tags: maven

I'm trying to perform a release using maven release.

```
mvn release:prepare
```

works fine, but using

```
mvn release:perform
```

gives me and error

```
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

in my pom.xml

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://(repo url)</developerConnection>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>svnrepo</id>
        <url>https://(repo url)</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>svnrepo</id>
    <username>test</username>
    <password>test</password>
</server>
```

I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

**YOU NEED TO INSTALL YOUR NETWORK ROOT SSL CERTIFICATE INTO JRE(Which java home maven is using) CACERTS. FOR ANY JAVA PKIX SSL EXAPTION YOU MAY FOLLOW THIS GUIDE.**

**How to get Root Certificate?**

1. Open Google Chrome and navigate to https url e.g. https://sourceforge.net/
2. Click on icon just besides your url. see following image.

[image]

3. Click on View Certificate.You can see hierarchy and select top most certificate in hierarchy
4. Confirm that certificate have ROOT word in its name.
5. Now just bellow that hierarchy part you can see a rectangle image of the certificate. Just drag that image and drop it to your desktop.

**NOW YOU HAVE YOUR ROOT CERTIFICATE!**

**HOW TO INSTALL THIS CERTIFICATE INTO JRE CACERTS?**

Before you proceed further do confirm you had located exactly that jre which is giving this error. Many times IDE uses jre which is bundled with it not system jre.

For your case Just type following command

> mvn -version

this command will give you path to java location (java home) your maven is using.Please use that path for following steps.

1. use keytool.exe inside your jre bin folder.
2. fire following command to place your certificate inside cacerts file

> keytool –import –noprompt –trustcacerts –alias ALIASNAME -file
>   /PATH/TO/YOUR/DESKTOP/CertificateName.cer -keystore
>   /PATH/TO/YOUR/JDK/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

**NOW YOUR PROBLEM IS RESOLVED!**